# $\frac{d}{dx}:C^1([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ as a closed, unbounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, relations, unbounded-operators

First recall that a (potentially unbounded) operator $T:D(T)\subseteq X\to Y$ is *closed* whenever $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset D(T)$ convergent to $x\in X_0$ and $(Tx_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ convergent in $X_1$ together imply that $x\in D(T)$ and $Tx=\lim_{n\to\infty}Tx_n$.

On the Wikipedia page for unbounded operators, differentiation [$\frac{d}{dx}:C^1([0,1])\to C([0,1])$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Example_2) is given as an example of a *closed*, unbounded operator. In this example, $X,Y$ are both taken to be $C([a,b])$ and $D(T)=C^1([a,b])$. As our unbounded operator we have $T=\frac{d}{dx}$.

Whilst I have no trouble seeing that in this example $T$ is unbounded, I am not so convinced that $T$ is closed. In particular, I know that $C^1([0,1])$ is dense in $C([0,1])$, but not closed; so it isn't so obvious that a convergent sequence $f_n\in C^1([0,1])$ should have limit $f\in C^1([0,1])$. How, exactly, should one proceed in trying to show this?

Comment: I added a source in the Wikipedia page which gives the details. It is Example 4.13-4 .

Comment: Just to check, that's the Kreyszig reference?

Comment: Yes, it is Kreyszig.

Comment: Thanks for that, Pedro, I'll be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is closed, you should check that if $f_n \in C^1([0,1])$ and $f_n \to f$, $f_n' \to g$ in $C([0,1])$, then $f \in C^1([0,1])$ and $f' = g$.

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we can write $f_n(x) = f_n(0) + \int_0^x f_n'(s) ds$. In particular, by sending $n \to \infty$, 
$$f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x g(s) ds$$ 
so $f \in C^1([0,1])$ and $f' = g$.

Comment: I knew that it had to involve the integral somehow - this clearly identifies how; a silly oversight on my part.